# JPA JoinColumn does not work

Tags: jpa, annotations

I have started with an example from a book. It was really a dummy oriented one and I am having a problem with the code the book gave.

Here is the code;

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String email;

@OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
           cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "address_fk")
private Address address;
//getter, setter, Constructor
```

--//-------------------------------------

```
@Entity
public class Address {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private String id;
private String city;
private String street;
private String number;
```

In here it is complaining on the JoinColumn annotation. It says the column address_fk is not found.

Is this an IDE related issue? Am I missing something?

Edit : No table yet created in the DB. I am expecting them to be seen on the DB automatically by my persistence.xml

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@JoinColumn` annotation to specify foreign column name to be `address_fk` instead of default `address_id` is fine.

What likely does not to work is [@GeneratedValue](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) with String. According specification only integral types as generated primary keys are portable.

Comment: some how it was complaining about the JoinColumn. When I removed it. The problem solved. Honestly, it is now better then one I choose before.

Comment: I also changed the Address's id type to Long as well.